# Bundler version wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having trouble creating a new Rails app. I'm using a fresh WSL2 + Ubuntu 18.04 install.

Long story short, I followed the Rails installation procedure from https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10 but when installing bundle using `gem install bundler`, I end up with 2 bundler versions (2.1.2 and 2.1.4).

If I stick with 2.1.2 webpacker throws an error, so I definitely need to install the newest version. The problem is, when I install 2.1.4 the default version remains 2.1.2, so then I go to `cd /.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default` and remove `bundler-2.1.2.gemspec`, and then I do a `gem install bundler --default` to get only v2.1.4 as default:

```
gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.1.4)
```

But here is the problem; if I run `bundler -v` I get:

```
bundler -v
Bundler version 2.1.2
```

But the **real** problem is that, when running `rails new`, it clearly *tries* to use 2.1.2 which inevitably fails.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem uninstall bundler --version 2.1.2`.

Answer (score 0):

From the app directory run these commands:

```sh
gem install bundler
bundle update --bundler
bundle install
```

This rebuilds the Gemfile.lock with the correct Bundler version.

EDIT: You can create the directory first with `rails new my_rails_app`, then do `cd .. ; rails new my_rails_app` after running the above commands.